# WinForm : How to load rad autocomplete textbox from database with text and value in a block

Tags: java, c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a code like this:

```
public void LoadDiseaes()
{
    da.OpenConnection();
    Disease disease = new Disease(da);
    txtDisease.AutoCompleteDataSource = disease.GetAll();
    txtDisease.AutoCompleteDisplayMember ="DiseaseName";
    txtDisease.AutoCompleteValueMember ="ID";
}
```

Initially, I have used above code to bind autocomplete `textbox(txtDisease)` with its `Datasource`.

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Then, after I selected particular disease and saved the record. This work fine.

My question is that when I want update that record I want to populate my `AutoComplete(txtDisease)` with the `Disease` from the Database with its Text and Value in a block which I have selected during saving the record but it gives me only a text and not value in background.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/editors-autocompletebox-auto-complete.html

You should make a RadListDataItemCollection, add the items inside and you're good to go.